# Aren't we a little overusing the "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" closing reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I feel like I see more and more this reason used, even in problems that aren't trivial for people knowing the basics of the topic.

Here's an example :

[Regex to remove the seconds from the time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421861/regex-to-remove-the-seconds-from-the-time-string)

I don't say it's a great question. But it seems perfectly legitimate and bad regexes wouldn't have made it better.

SO might be a little hard to the newbie here and in similar cases. It looks like the change in the closing system might have made SO a little less friendly to new users.

Comment: The closing reason may not be the perfect choice, but simple "gimmeh a regex" questions have always been frowned upon by some (and happily answered by others). That's nothing new and whether your question ends up closed, answered, or both, is down to chance.

Comment: I think that that is actually the correct closing reason. The OP only claims he tried many regexes, but none are included in the post. He did **not** demonstrate what they tried to do.

Comment: I browsed through all of the OPs questions. What I think is actually the most interesting is that what seemed to be the only question he'd actually put any real effort into was actually one of the few that had absolutely no response from the community. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/15767993/806549)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question was posted without any indication what programming language the were trying to use. That alone is a classic case of needing to provide more information before the question can be properly answered.

Additionally, although they say they have tried things, they haven't *shown* what they have tried in the question so there is nothing to correct. If they could show even a broken attempt it would 1) allow people to surmise the language being used and 2) show how far along into the problem they were so somebody can start their answer at the most useful place to start instead of just doing all the work for them.

Which one of those two issues you consider to be a more major problem may determine which close reason you think is ideal. The one used primarily indicates the latter, which seems reasonable to me. Either way, the question deserved being put on hold until the OP makes the effort to fix it.

Comment: in which case the "unclear" close reason should have been used, if any

Comment: Almost all regex questions are posted "without any indication what programming language the were trying to use". I agree this is a problem, and one I'd really like to see adressed (I pondered a few times making a dedicated feature request), but it's a separate one.

Comment: @JanDvorak True. I was getting there, see edits :)

Comment: I disagree but the community of SO did choose so I'll accept this only answer.

Comment: @dystroy Votes already indicate community consensus; the checkmark should indicate the OP's agreement. If you disagree with the top-voted answer, you should _not_ accept it. This is not so severe on meta, but if you act like this on the actual SE sites be aware that upvotes can mean something trivial like "looks good" or "oh, cute unicorn image", while the checkmark should really be considered more like a "seal of approval" suggesting that the OP has up a certain degree verified that the answer does not only look good but _really_ solves the problem for _them_.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I get your point but I think meta votes are nothing like other SE sites votes. People coming later to this question will probably be more interested by the consensus, which is a kind of guideline, than by my personal opinion, don't you think ?

Comment: @dystroy Sure enough, as you state, meta works differently. Then again, community consensus does not necessarily establish itself within a mere hour - think of all the timezones where folks are currently (supposed to be) asleep. And no matter what you accept or not, the highest voted answer will always float right beneath

Comment: @TobiasKienzler OK, you almost convinced me. Caleb, I remove my acceptation for now (and I'll accept your question again later if nothing drastically changes).

Answer (score 5):

Generally, I think the question is a perfect example of not demonstrating any understanding. Bad regexes would absolutely have made the question better, because then it could be seen whether it was a typo, a fundamental flaw in the OPs regex skills or something completely different (ie. the regex he has might be correct, but he is unable to get the right output from it).

**And**, if you look at the other questions the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075401/gilamran) has asked, I'd say he was due for some tougher love. 12 questions, and of the 5 newest, **NONE** show anything what-so-ever.

Specifically, I read two points in your question. One is whether "gimme regex|sql|whatever" questions are ok. I say no, and I think we just differ on that. ;) Those are frequently (and in this case) just LMGTFY - in this case I've easily found 5 candidates for trying a regexp that might work.

The other is whether we should go easy on new users. I felt I got a break when I started here, so I've asked a couple of times and I'd say that the community tends to be unanimous on this. See for instance [the comments and answers to this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184438/213634)

Comment: The point you make regarding this specific user is interesting (hence the +1) but in fact my question was more general than on this specific question/user/.

Comment: @dystroy I've updated my answer to include some more detail.